# Visual Web Developer 2010 Express User-Scope Settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Per the title, I can't figure out how to create user-scope entries in the default Settings.settings file for my web application.  I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.  All of them are application scope by default, and I can't change it - there is no drop down box.  Some googling and searching yielded nothing - the MSDN page makes a reference to user-scope entries (and I know I used them in VS C# 2010 Express)...

So...

What am I missing? I feel really dumb.  This seems to mean you can't create user-scope settings.

If I can't create user-scope settings, how can I programagically modify entries in Settings.settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-scoped settings in web applications doesn't make many sense. How do you difference between users? Where do you store that values?

In windows applications makes sense, because there is an XML file per application.

Try to do that manually using ASP.NET users, and saving values in a database.

Comment: Ah. Ok.  So, say I had a list of user-configurable entries. I need to set up a database, then, for any persistent storage of these values?

Comment: @uscere90: In summary, yes. Or may be you can try using membership options from ASP.NET.